# Show that $x<x^n<1$ when $x,n\in(0,1)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Show that $x<x^n<1$ when $x,n\in(0,1)$

My attempt:
If I could show the function $x^n-x$ is positive in the given interval...

$x^n-x = x(x^{n-1}-1)$
Since $x$ is positive we can ignore it and consider only $x^{n-1}-1$.
I feel stuck here. It seems I need to show $x^{n-1} \gt 1$ which doesn't look any better.. Any help?

---

[Here](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/hkajxoxjat) is a desmos graph that I've been using..

Comment: I think using $n$ for a real number between $0$ and $1$ is misleading. Note that $n-1\lt 0$ so setting $n-1=-y$ we have $x^{n-1}=x^{-y}=(x^{-1})^y$ and $x^{-1}\gt 1$ and $y\gt 0$.

Comment: @MarkBennet Sorry I see now it is very misleading :/ I came to this from taylor series and got carried away... I'll give it a try with your substitution. It seems I need to understand why $1.1^y$ is $\gt 1$ when $y\in (0,1)$.

Comment: I can see why  $1.1^y$ is $\gt 1$ when $y\gt 1$. But when $y\in (0,1)$ I find it a bit hard to convince..

Comment: $n$ is misleading because $n$ is often used for a (positive) integer, and though it ought not to make a difference, the association is strong.

Comment: It depends how powers are defined. $x^y=e^{y\ln x}$ and with $x\gt 1, y\gt 0$ we have $\ln x \gt 0$ and $y\ln x \gt 0$ so that $e^{y\ln x}=1+y\ln x +\dots$ where all the terms are positive and the value is greater than $1$

Comment: I agree it is misleading :( that symbol in my previous comment was supposed to be a sad face haha @MarkBennet

Comment: $1.1^{0.2} = e^{0.2\times \ln 1.1} = e^{0.2\times (\text something ~positive)} \gt 1$   Looks I get this XD Thank you so much @MarkBennet

Comment: Now I could use your $e^{..}$ trick :   $x^n = e^{n\ln x} = e^{-|p|} = \dfrac{1}{e^{|p|}} \lt 1$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $x\in (0,1)$, then $f(t)=x^t$ is strictly decreasing because $f'(t) = x^t \ln x <0 $.

Thus $x^1<x^n<x^0$, i.e. $x < x^n <1$

Comment: Oh you chose the variable to be the exponent. Pretty clever! I get your proof but I'm also looking for some way to explain this w/o using calculus if possible.. Thank you so much you're awesome:)

Comment: I can explain why $x^t$ is less than $x$ for $t\gt 1$ like this :  $0.3^{2} =$ $30$ percent of $0.3$ which is clearly less than $0.3$. But $t <1$ completely throws me off. It seems I don't know how to interpret $x^t$ in real life when $t<1$

Comment: @rsadhvika Maybe you can refer to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_function

Comment: Do you need calculus if you're willing to accept that that $\exp$ is monotone and that $\ln x <0$ for $x<0$?

Comment: @KBDave that should do haha I've been reading the wiki link given by @Zero and found a nice explanation -  In the function $f(x,t) = x^t$, we can interpret $x$ as `rate` of growth/decay per unit time, and $t$ as `time`. Then  $0.3^{0.7} $ is clearly greater than $0.3$ because we're just waiting for the time $0.7$. (We must wait for `one full unit of time` to decay by 30 percent)